# failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: open /private/tmp/AVScanB2wT: permission denied

Tags: macos, docker, dockerfile

Getting this error during docker build command.

`failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: open /private/tmp/AVScanB2wT: permission denied`

Environment:

- Mac OS 11.4 Big Sur with Symantec Endpoint Protection 14.3.1
- Docker Desktop 3.5.1.7

Steps taken so far

- Reset Docker Desktop to factory settings
- `Clean / Purge data` from Docker Desktop preferences
- Re-installed Docker Desktop
- `chmod 777 /private/tmp`
- `chmod 777 /private/tmp` inside Dockerfile (Mostly unnecessary)
- Gave full disk permission to Docker Desktop from Mac Preferences
- Named dockerfile as `Dockerfile`

Please let me know if anyone came across similar error.

Comment: Problem solved by `sudo chmod -R 777 /private/tmp/AVScanB2wT` One more directory popped up in the error message and provided 777 permissions to fix it.

Comment: Typically a `/tmp` is `chmod 1777` for the sticky bit. Not sure if MacOS with `/private`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short term fix
`sudo chmod -R 777 /private/tmp/AVScanB2wT`

Long term fix
Disable buildx in docker desktop experimental features.

```
"features": {
    "buildkit": false
}
```

[image: Docker Desktop Preferences]

Comment: Where should we edit this settings?

Comment: @tutiplain In Preferences of Docker desktop. Earlier it was under "Experimental Features"

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else, this happened to me when I was trying to build a Django app for the first time. I had not created the `requirements.txt` file from Pipenv yet. The containers were failing to build, but it was throwing this error like it didn't have access to the directory. I ran `pipenv requirements > requirements.txt` and worked.